1-norm-ball is equal to convex hull of vertices
Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Let $\epsilon\in\mathbb{R}^+$ and $x_0\in\mathbb{R}^n$.
Show: $B^{||.||_{1}}_{\epsilon}(x_0) = \text{conv}\{x_{0}\pm\epsilon e_i : i = 1,...,n\}$.
(I found this statement in multiple textbooks, but no proof was given.)

Showing that $B^{||.||_{1}}_{\epsilon}(x_0)$ is convex and contains the set of vertices is easy and gives us "$\supseteq$". For the other direction, we need to express any arbitrary $x\in B^{||.||_{1}}_{\epsilon}(x_0)$ as a convex combination of vertices.
Here is what i tried (it failed) and need help on:
$$ x = x_0+x-x_0 = x_o + \sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-(x_0)_i)e_i$$
Set $\alpha_i:= x_i-(x_0)_i$ and $\lambda_i^+:= \frac{\text{max}(\alpha_i,0)}{r}$, $\lambda_i^-:=\frac{\text{max}(-\alpha_i,0)}{r}$.
Then $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_i^+(x_0+re_i)+\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_i^-(x_0-re_i)= x$
and the weights are equal to $1$, if $x$ is on the boundary. If $x$ is an interior point this fails. I have tried modifying the weights for some time now, any help is much appreciated.

Assume wlog $x_0=0$, just to simplify the notations. Given $x\in B^{\|\cdot\|_1}_\epsilon(0)$, let $y$ be a boundary point such that $x\in[0,y]$. You already know that $y$ is a convex combination of the vertiges, and you will easily show that so is $0$. The conclusion follows.
